# Maven 3.5 - Jump to source not working in intelliJ when -Drevision set in maven.config

Tags: maven-3

As you may know Maven 3.5 bring the possibility to set the project version in every poms in case of multi module project.

I added the code `-Drevision=1.3.0-SNAPSHOT` in a new file: .mvn/maven.config

My pom.xml contain now:

```
<groupId>fr.laposte.geniusback</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>${revision}</version>
```

But when I want to navigate through my modules with cmd+click, I always open a "compiled file".

Moreover integration tests are not working without compiling entirely the project (`mvn clean install`).

Comment: yep this oddly doesn't work in intellij but works like charm in sts.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [release notes](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/05/intellij-idea-2018-2-eap2-breakpoint-intentions-enhancements-in-code-refactoring-and-more/), this feature seems to be available in IntelliJ 2018.2 EAP2 .

Despite what @pawan-tejwan said, I could not make it work in Spring Tool Suite (and to my knowledge it is not yet supported in Eclipse'm2e (hence STS).

This is a shame as this feature is really usefull to avoid merge conflicts on poms with feature branches (if we define .mvn/maven.config to be "merge=ours" in the .gitattributes file).